# Interaction term as a Covariate

Tags: interaction, r-squared

Can I use an Interaction Term as a covariate, without any interaction with my primary variable of interest?

$Y = a + bX_1 + cX_2 + dX_3 + eX_2*X_3 + error$

where a is the intercept, and b, c, d, e are the slopes, and $X_1$ is the primary variable of interest.

Does it make sense to include an interaction in **covariates/controls only** if it significantly improves the overall fit of the model?

Also, wondering if this indeed is legit, why is it not a common practice in papers in economics? (or perhaps I should ask myself why have I been so clueless about it!)

Comment: Model specification is highly subject matter dependent and you didn't give us this type of background information.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I was wondering whether this is possible in principle (and is a norm).

But here is a model,

Violent Crime = Intercept + Average Income + Ethnic Heterogeneity + Income Inequality + Ethnic Heterogeneity*Income Inequality.

In such a model, how do you see the interaction term - considering all variable turn out to be significant and the interaction terms significantly improves the r-squared.

Comment: Go back to my comment.  That should drive the process, not what you observe with regard to p-values and $R^2$.